# data per block in CUDA -- does it broadcast in one transaction?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

i have a data array that is per-block. 
i have N blocks inside a cuda Grid and a constant array of data "block_data[]" with size N.

so, all threads in a given block 'X' access block_data[X] just one time, and do something with that value.

my question is: does this broadcast scheme work efficiently?
if not, what approach should i take?

edit after comments: my only problem with constant memory is its limited size, since i could have more than 64K blocks. That would mean more than 64KB

regards

Comment: do you modify block_data in your cuda kernel ? if not, it makes sense to allocate it in constant memory which is precisely optimized for that type of accesses

Comment: it does not change, in fact it is a lookup table. The only problem of constant memory is that it is 64KB for the whole kernel execution am i right?

Comment: yes, there is only 64kb of constant mem in total. btw I remembered that Fermi GPUs can also load read-only data from global memory through constant cache (i.e. load uniform) if the address does not depend on a thread ID (which is probably your case). So i think it won't be any performance implications if you use block_data as it is

Comment: Yipes, most lookup tables are not well-served by constant memory.  @asm is right, the load uniform instruction is probably your best bet.

Comment: ok i get your idea now, let me check the logic and ill answer back

Comment: from what i understand, the load uniform instruction is at a ptx level. So this instruction is supposed to be generated automatically by the compiler under fermi-kepler?, when accesing something like block_array[blockIdx.x] for all threads in a block?

Comment: yes it is ptx instruction. Just make sure that block_array is declared with const qualifier. Then you can check the generated ptx code to see if load uniform is indeed used

Comment: checked the ptx code and indeed the "ldu" was generated. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just use a normal global memory access then the transaction is fairly inefficient, although depending on how much work your kernel is doing the impact is probably quite small.

I'm assuming `sizeof(block_data)` is one byte (inferred from your question "...could have more than 64K blocks. That would mean more than 64KB").

- If the operation is cached in L1 then you will fetch 128 bytes for the one bit of info you need (`sizeof(block_data)`), if other warps in the block request the same data then they should get from L1. The efficiency of the load is 1/128 but you should only pay that once for the block.
- If the operation is not cached in L1 (e.g. you pass "-dlcm=cg" to the assembler) then you will fetch 32 bytes. The efficiency is 1/32 but you pay that once for each warp.
- Once the data is loaded, it is broadcast to all threads in the warp.

An alternative would be to mark the data as `const __restrict__` which indicates to the compiler that the data is a) read-only and b) not aliased by any other pointer. Since the compiler can detect that the access is uniform then it can optimise the access to use one of the read-only caches (e.g. constant cache or, on compute capability >=3.5, read-only data cache aka texture cache).

Comment: thanks Tom, at the moment i tested with L1 using 4 bytes per element of the array (int). The PTX code generated indeed used "ldu" instruction however i expected it to run faster. I am testing on a Geforce gtx 680. I still have to test if the other options you mentioned (try -dlcm=cg  and add 'const __restrict__').

Comment: Just reporting results: i tried with "__restrict__" and adding "-dlcm=cg". Performance was approximately the same as without using them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the values in `block_data[N]` array, better use the concept of shared memory `__shared__`. If you are not changing the value of `block_data[N]`, use `__const__` or use the concept of cache. By using L2 Cache, you can get 1536KB of memory (Kepler).

Comment: updated question, block_data is constant and only read one time.

Comment: If it's read one time, try using L2 cache. It is faster. If you use L1 cache, 64KB memory is shared by both Shared Memory and L1 cache.

Comment: my only concern is the one time read, i think i am screwed with cache in this case. What about broadcast for a warp from global memory, does that exist in kepler? edit: ill take a look at L2 cache in more detail

Comment: so with L2 (since its on by default) you actually mean to leave the data in global mem and just read the common value from every thread? (under kepler arch)

Comment: Take a look at F.4 and F.5 in Programming Guide 4.2. broadcasting changes for compute capability of the device.